# Most object orientated way to create and read a list of multiple options?

Tags: python, oop

So the title sounds a little confusing but I shall attempt to be thorough in my explanation. I am currently programming a bot in Python that is designed to respond appropriately with puns based on a keyword presented to it. Each word has multiple potential responses but equally, each response could be used for multiple words.

For example, if a word in `cat_input` (see below) is found, it will produce a random response from `cat_output`.

```
cat_input= ['cat','purr','meow','claw','felidae','puss','paw']
cat_output= ["I know the purrfect pun for that one.",
             "I only tell these puns beclaws I have to."
            ]
```

However the word 'paw' and 'claw' could also be used for other animals and other animals may also have the same potential outputs as seen below:

```
dog_input=['dog','woof','bark','paw','canine','pup','puppy','claw']

dog_output=["I only tell these puns beclaws I have to.",
            "I knew a dog who was a little ruff on me."
          ]
```

As you can see, this isn't as optimal as it could be which brings me to the title question: What is the best object orientated method to be able to categorize certain words to certain responses with less repetition and (if possible), can you produce a basic example to explain how it might look?

Comment: Why differentiate the input as 'dog' input and 'cat' input? You could just map each word to some phrase (or many of them). In that case you wouldn't need an OOP at all.

Comment: It seems like you have the problem of not being able to implement any solution to your question -- not expressing a solution in a more or less object orientated way. Perhaps first you should just write a straightforward, non-oo solution?

Comment: This is an odd question, because it's not clear how a chat bot would benefit from an OO-approach. You could make a `Cat` and a `Dog` class, but that would be nonsensical. There's no need to model cats and dogs in a chat program. Better would be some classes like maybe `Trigger` and `Response`, but... why? What functionality would they hold? They would be nothing but containers for strings. What you're looking for is a mapping from trigger words to outputs, which is what the `dict` class is for. In my opinion, OOP has no place here (except for a chat bot class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random
class petPun(object):
    def __init__(self, species,inputWordList,outputSentenceList):
        self.species=species
        self.inputWordList=inputWordList
        self.outputSentenceList=outputSentenceList
    def makePun(self,inputWord):
        if inputWord in self.inputWordList:
            random.shuffle(self.outputSentenceList)
            return self.outputSentenceList[0]
        else:
            return "Invalid Word"

animalInputDict={"Dog":['Dog','Woof','Bark','Paw','Canine','Pup','Puppy','Claw'],"Cat":['Cat','Purr','Meow','Claw','Felidae','Puss','Paw']}
animalOutputDict={"Dog":["I only tell these puns beclaws I have to.","I knew a dog who was a little ruff on me."],"Cat":["I know the purrfect pun for that one.","I only tell these puns beclaws I have to."]}
while True:
    currentSpecies=input("What species of pun do you want?")

    punObject=petPun(currentSpecies,animalInputDict[currentSpecies],animalOutputDict[currentSpecies])
    word=input("What word do you want to base your pun off of?")
    pun=punObject.makePun(word)
    print(pun)
    exitUser=input("Do you want to stop making puns?")
    if exitUser=="Yes":
        break
```

I hope that this helps. If it does not fix your needs, just let me know. Also, it would be wise to make it more user-safe. You can implement more animals by adding them to the two dictionaries. Another approach would be polymorphic inheritance, and you could try that if this does not work.

Comment: This is definitely on the right lines although I should note that the puns may not always be animal based. There could be puns for various topics implemented but this is definitely a good starting point through creating inputs based on certain categories (in this case, based on if it's an animal).

Comment: It does not have to be just animals. Add anything you want in the two dictionaries, change the variable names, and you can implement any pun you want.

Comment: Why do you require OOP?

Comment: I believe my thoughts of what OOP is might have been incorrect but I was aiming to try aim to reduce the amount of repetitive coding (and possibly the inputs and outputs) to make it as coding friendly as possible. However, I feel the dictionary approach is a viable and best approach to this situation. Thank you guys for your inputs and suggestions :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's to abstract, or i didn't really get what you want. But why you have different input? i think it does not matter... I would create a simply dict which matches each word to it potential outputs, and then grep one randomly from it...

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a base class `Animal` from which `Dog` and `Cat` inherit? Then you can check to see if the word `paw` matches an animal, then pick one of your `Animal` instances randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
import random

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, keywords, outputs):
        self.keywords = keywords
        self.outputs = outputs

    def inp(self, keyword):
        if keyword in self.keywords:
            self.outp()

    def outp(self):
        print(random.choice(self.outputs))

my_cat = Animal(["cat", "purr"], ["purrfect pun"])
my_cat.inp("purr")
```

For a keyword which could be for more than one animal, you could do this:

```
my_cat = Animal(...)
my_dog = Animal(...)
my_bonobo = Animal(...)

animals = [my_cat, my_dog, my_bonobo]
for animal in animals:
    animal.inp("paw")
```